# pandas cumsum replace the result calculated by cumsum with the content at the specified position

Tags: python, pandas

data

```
data = [
    {"content": "1", "title": "app sotre", "info": "", "time": 1578877014},
    {"content": "2", "title": "app", "info": "", "time": 1579877014},
    {"content": "3", "title": "pandas", "info": "", "time": 1582877014},
    {"content": "12", "title": "a", "info": "", "time": 1582876014},
    {"content": "33", "title": "apple", "info": "", "time": 1581877014},
    {"content": "16", "title": "banana", "info": "", "time": 1561877014},
    {"content": "aa", "title": "banana", "info": "", "time": 1582876014},
]
```

my code

```
def cumsum(is_test=False):
    cdata = pd.to_numeric(s.str.get('content'), errors='coerce').cumsum()
    if is_test:
        print(list(cdata))
        return list(cdata)
    for i, v in enumerate(s):
        s.iloc[i]['content'] = str(cdata[i])
    return list(s)

assert cumsum(is_test=True)==[1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 18.0, 51.0, 67.0, 'nan']
```

res is not true, how to solve?
final how to my code pythonic way？
Replace the result calculated by cumsum with the content at the specified position。
i hope data is :

```
[{'content': '1.0', 'title': 'app sotre', 'info': '', 'time': 1578877014},
 {'content': '3.0', 'title': 'app', 'info': '', 'time': 1579877014}, 
{'content': '6.0', 'title': 'pandas', 'info': '', 'time': 1582877014}, 
{'content': '18.0', 'title': 'a', 'info': '', 'time': 1582876014}, 
{'content': '51.0', 'title': 'apple', 'info': '', 'time': 1581877014}, 
{'content': '67.0', 'title': 'banana', 'info': '', 'time': 1561877014}, 
{'content': 'nan', 'title': 'banana', 'info': '', 'time': 1582876014}]
```

Comment: Your cumsum returns strings, and your assert has floats in it. - `'1.0'` vs `1.0`

Comment: @h4z3 I have a judgment，var is_test  =True  return [1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 18.0, 51.0, 67.0, 'nan']
if is_test=False return [{'content': '1.0', 'title': 'app sotre', 'info': '', 'time': 1578877014}]

Comment: Read about comparing floats and floating point errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest loop by zipped original list `data` with `Series` `cdata` and then set new values:

```
cdata = pd.to_numeric(s.str.get('content'), errors='coerce').cumsum()
print (cdata)
0     1.0
1     3.0
2     6.0
3    18.0
4    51.0
5    67.0
6     NaN
dtype: float64

for old, new in zip(data, cdata):
    old['content'] = str(new)

print (data)
[{'content': '1.0', 'title': 'app sotre', 'info': '', 'time': 1578877014}, 
 {'content': '3.0', 'title': 'app', 'info': '', 'time': 1579877014}, 
 {'content': '6.0', 'title': 'pandas', 'info': '', 'time': 1582877014}, 
 {'content': '18.0', 'title': 'a', 'info': '', 'time': 1582876014},
 {'content': '51.0', 'title': 'apple', 'info': '', 'time': 1581877014}, 
 {'content': '67.0', 'title': 'banana', 'info': '', 'time': 1561877014},
 {'content': 'nan', 'title': 'banana', 'info': '', 'time': 1582876014}]
```

Comment: hi，i not understand use loop,What's so special about doing this？